# Can I use `overflow: scroll` on a div with variable height?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to use `overflow: scroll` on a div that has height set to auto?

I have a div with an unordered list inside of it. The amount of items in the list is variable so there is no way I can use a fixed height. The div that contains the unordered list is where the scrollbars need to be, here is my code:

```
#page {
    height: auto; /* default */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

As stated, the unordered list is contained within the #page div. The height of the page is assigned by the unordered list's value. Is there a way to make overflow: scroll work on a div with variable height like this or must I use JavaScript to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what development platform are you working with?

Comment: I'm using PhoneGap to create an application for iOS and Android. If you're not familiar with PhoneGap it allows you to compile applications using html, css and javascript. Great stuff :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### One way of approaching this design...

Suppose that you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <ul>
            <li>Some list items...</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.main` block is fitted to the page, for example, by absolute positioning:

```
.main {
    border: 2px dashed blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

The `.inner` block holds the navigation list that can cause scrolling:

```
.inner {
    border: 2px dotted red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

In this example, I constrain the height of the `.inner` block to fit within `.main`,
and set `overflow-y: scroll`, which creates a scroll bar contained within the edges
of the container block.

You may have to adapt this to your mobile platform, but the concept should still apply.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ac4xT/

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, if it has variable height (auto), it will never have overflow in the y axis (vertically), because the div will always grow to fit its contents.

`overflow: scroll` will force it to present a scrollbar, but it will always be disabled, because the contents will never extend beyond the displayed pane.

If you want vertical scrolling, you have to define a height, either in px, %, or em.

If you do `height: 100%`, the div will fill the height of the page, and scroll content that extends beyond the window's viewport height.

If you have a header area, try something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <p>Header</p>
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

For a fixed-height header (per the comments), use absolute positioning with a top and botom value to position the scrollable div below it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <p>Header</p>
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p><p>Body</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding on your answer slightly to help my situation? What do you recommend I do because the height of the div is variable?

Comment: I just tried this and it came out like this: http://i.imgur.com/hn07vPH.png It doesn't scroll down the whole page to the bottom of the list

Comment: updated my answer with a more complete solution.  You'll have to tweak the % values to get it to look exactly right.

Comment: This is one way I thought about approaching the matter already. Although the header of the application requires a fixed height so sadly this is not an option. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: this is not true if you set max-height

Comment: @jskidd3 I just saw your latest comment. It's 9 years later, but I finally answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use max-height on the div?

max-height sets the maximum height to which an element can expand. I suppose what you want is the div to never go out of the screen. So you can set a max-height and then overflow: auto;

Comment: I'm unaware of this property, please adapt your answer more to my problem so I understand what you mean :) Thanks